# Traverse zipped input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashmap, nested-lists

I have my user input input in the form of nested list. I want to make combinations out of it and it's like as follows:

```
Input: [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6], 
        [7, 8, 9]]
```

Zipping it using zip function in python so that traversing would be easy.

```
Zipped Output [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]

Tree structure to be traversed ex:
                        1
               /        |         \
               2        5         8
              / | \    /| \     /  | \
             3  6  9   3 6 9    3   6  9
```

Expected ouput

```
1,2,3
1,2,6
1,2,9
1,5,3
1,5,6
1,5,9
...
...
7,8,9
```

I'm not getting how to achieve such combinations using dictionaries or maps or if there is other way to do this please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function:

```
from itertools import product

l = [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
for p in product(*l):
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 6)
(1, 2, 9)
(1, 5, 3)
(1, 5, 6)
(1, 5, 9)
...
(7, 8, 9)
```

Calling the function like this (without any additional params) returns the cartesian product of the 3 "sets".

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!

Answer (score 2):

People may introduce you itertools as what Hunter McMillen commented. You can find better solution from the website he provided.

Here is a simple code that also does the same job.

```
A = l = [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
for i in A[0]:
    for j in A[1]:
        for k in A[2]:
            print([i, j, k])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!The solution provided by him was more generic.